# If $16^{\sin ^2x}=5$, then what is $2^{\cos^2x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I happened to create this problem and solved it. I used only basic algebra and trigonometry. I thought it was a fun problem, so I wanted to expose the problem to the public. Please provide an exact answer.

Comment: You can see what I did by right clicking on the equations, then selecting TEX Commands.  You can also consult this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$2^{\cos^2x}=2^{1-\sin^2x}=\frac2{\sqrt[4]{16^{\sin^2x}}}=\frac2{\sqrt[4]5}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{\cos^2 x}= 2^{1-\sin^2 x}=\frac{2}{2^{\sin^2 x}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt[4]{5}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$16^{\sin^2 x} = 5 \to 16 \times 2^{-4\cos^2 x} = 5 \to \left({2^{\cos^2 x}}\right)^{-4} = 5 \times 2^{-4} \to 2^{\cos^2 x} = \frac2{5^{1/4}} $$

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

$$2^{\cos^2 x}= 2^{1-\sin^2 x}=\frac{2}{2^{\sin^2 x}}=\frac2{5^{1/4}}$$